# update firestore document field once created using cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In one version of my published application, there is a bug that creates a document in my collection, and in one of the fields in this document (called "Popularity"), the field equals a string "null" instead of a string of a number, say "4.5".

What it causes is that on the client-side when a user reads the data and tries to use `Double.parseDouble("null")` it gives an error while it should have used `Double.parseDouble("4.5")`.

I want to add some cloud function trigger that will listen to any document that is created in that collection and if the created document has this field that equals to "null", to update it to "0.0".

My firestore is built as follows:

Users (collection) - > userId (document) -> fields (Popularity, ID, Title)

I'm new to cloud functions and I am not sure if I use correctly the .update in the end as all I could find is examples for `.onUpdate` and not for `.onCreate` examples.

I tried to use the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('Users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const newValue = snap.data();

        const Popularity = newValue.Popularity;
      
        if (Popularity != "null") {
            return null;
        }
        
        if (Popularity == "null") {
            return snap.update({
            Popularity: "0.0"
            }, {merge: true});

        }
    });
```

But I got the following error in my log:

```
TypeError: snap.update is not a function
```

and

```
TypeError: snap.update is not a function
```

I also tried to use:

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('Users/{bookId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const data = change.after.data();
        const previousData = change.before.data();

        const oldDocument = change.before.data();


        if (data.Popularity != 'null' && previousData.Popularity != 'null') {
            return null;
        }
        
        if (data.Popularity == 'null' || previousData.Popularity == 'null') {
            return change.after.ref.set({Popularity: '0.0'}, {merge: true});
        }
    });
```

But then I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Popularity' of undefined
```

Is there anything else I'm missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `snap` is a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), which (if you check its documentation) does indeed not have an `update()` method. To update the document that the snapshot came from, you'll want to call `snap.ref.update(...)`.